# django/python - db hits while accessing variables

Tags: python, django

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, blank=True)
```

For above model suppose we have a object "appuser" which we have rendered in template

Does django hits User db each time when we use it like appuser.user.username in our code??

Any help on how in django/python db lookups are done while accessing foreign key and many-to-many variables ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should carefully read through this for all details to database access optimization: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/optimization/

And `select_related()`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

As for a quick answer to your question: It depends on how you've retrieved the object

With

```
appuser = AppUser.objects.get(pk=id)
```

it will hit the database separately for appuser.user.

But with

```
appuser = AppUser.objects.select_related().get(pk=id)
```

It will do a joined query, so accessing appuser.user does not trigger an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Logging should be enabled if settings.DEBUG is set to True. As for your question, yes, this will AppUser will join with the User table(using the primary key) when you do a appuser.user.username.

If you are running the dev webserver, you should be able to see the logs on the console.

Answer (score 0):

it's on the docs

[querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

[when querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

to reduce db hits, check Béres Botond answer